# Check appointment is modified in Calendar iteself OR by EWS API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to sync calendar items to our application by using a windows service.
So i sent appointments to outlook calendar. Later i just want to pull appointments which are modified only in calendar.  Is that possible, If i am using same login parameters?
Or is there any other parameters i can check?
Already checked IsDirty & it is always false.

Answer (score 0):

When you update an appointment (or any Exchange store items) you should get back the changeKey for that item in the response https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-identifiers-in-exchange so you can use that to track further changes or to filter out clientside changes depending on how you syncing the items.